# Apache Server taking longer time

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web-services, ubuntu

I have deployed my PHP API on a Linux based server. It's users are 40000-50000. Server has Disk space 20GB and out of that, 15GB is used. I have used MySQL for Database. GZip is enabled and the response JSON on http://example.com/getData is nearly equal to 100KB. Initially, it used to take 2-3 seconds on each getData call (which includes querying from data table and processing on PHP), but now it is taking more than 15 seconds for a single request. I have checked the CPU usage by TOP command in linux. This is the CPU status:

top - 09:30:44 up 14:44,  3 users,  load average: 1.16, 2.54, 2.28
Tasks: 222 total,   1 running, 221 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  6.2%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 92.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.2%st
Mem:   2051652k total,  1576444k used,   475208k free,   204408k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   456548k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
15942 www-data  20   0  320m  14m 6480 S    1  0.7   0:04.50 apache2
15356 mysql     20   0 1320m  52m 7448 S    1  2.6   1:00.19 mysqld
15973 www-data  20   0  321m  15m 6444 S    1  0.8   0:06.75 apache2
15811 www-data  20   0  318m  12m 5648 S    1  0.6   0:04.33 apache2
28989 root      20   0 96716 3928 2948 S    1  0.2   0:00.03 sshd
15806 www-data  20   0  323m  17m 6756 S    0  0.9   0:04.10 apache2
15807 www-data  20   0  321m  16m 6708 S    0  0.8   0:04.83 apache2
15817 www-data  20   0  322m  16m 6416 S    0  0.8   0:06.19 apache2
15832 www-data  20   0  320m  14m 6416 S    0  0.7   0:04.11 apache2
15838 www-data  20   0  320m  14m 6416 S    0  0.7   0:04.05 apache2
15849 www-data  20   0  321m  15m 6416 S    0  0.8   0:06.15 apache2
15851 www-data  20   0  321m  15m 6424 S    0  0.8   0:04.26 apache2
15853 www-data  20   0  320m  15m 6740 S    0  0.8   0:05.45 apache2
15856 www-data  20   0  323m  18m 6644 S    0  0.9   0:04.68 apache2

All the queries running time is less than 0.01 second and the microtime difference between end and start of the getData function is 0.51.

What may be the reasons of this slow response on browser?

Answer (score 0):

I bet for DNS lookups in apache logs. Verify  “HostnameLookups” are off in your apache config.

Comment: HostnameLookups is off in my apache config file. Turning or or off doesn't reflect any changes on slow response.

Answer (score 0):

It could probably be the logs that is stored in your system , it holds records of application activities ex time, date and much more  , that's a major thing in system logs as it reduces the performance of any application activities.

Comment: What to do with those logs? I have deleted the compressed unnecessary logs. I have removed all logging from php code. I restarted the apache2. No change on speed. What to do?

Comment: from the readings your data storage are mostly consumed and has been established via the total usage of the space , however it is hard to identify why the service runs slow when your consume is high! Of your space,  check the storage and where the data being stored or increase the size .. there are many ways as its hard to monitor your application activity